# .mp4 file used for streaming and local play. What is the difference?

Tags: video-streaming

What I understand is that in the case of a .MP4 file (local file), Audio and Video data need not be stored in an interleaved fashion. This is unlike in a .TS file, where TS packets containing Audio and those containing Video are interspersed appropriately so that the player gets audio and video in time. So, how does this happen in the case of MP4?

Answer (score 0):

Fist off, MP4 is uasuall interleaved. It's just not a requirement. MP4 allmost always interlease chunks. A chunk can can contain one or more audio or video frames. MP4 is a container designed to be read from media with a fast random access time, like a hard drive. Ts is a container (actually it has many properties of a protocol as well, but that's a larger topic) that is designed for streaming with no (over the air television broadcast) or or slow (DVD) seek speeds. So on a hard disk, where it takes less than one frame to seek in a file, it doesn't matter. But with a stream where seeking is impossible, it matters a great deal. When you play an MP4 over the internet, it's called pseudo streaming and requires the MP4 have at least a sane amount of interleaving chunks, or will buffer enough up to playback. You can also seek over http using range requests, but it is very slow seek speed.